# SimpleDataForma ParseException: Unparseable date?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I have "2019-05-21T17:43:05.129Z"
and I am using the format '  val EXPIRE_DATE_FORMAT = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH)'

I want to ignore timezone that is why I have XXX at the end.
What is the issue with my dataFormat?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. On my computer your formatter parses your string into `Tue May 21 19:43:05 CEST 2019` with no signs of error. I also fail to see what sense it would make to ignore the `Z` (for UTC or “Zulu time zone”). Maybe if you’d explain, we could help you better.